# Motor driver board - wingxine - need help with wiring

Tags: datasheet, motor-controller, pinout

Recently I bought this [motor driver](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/230715150993?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_1450wt_975) but I didn't get wiring diagram for it (it's last time I bought something like this). I would like someone to provide some wiring schematics for this motor driver if it is possible... Great would also be explanation of pins on the board...

[image: Motor driver board]

Another thing I would like to know is what motor can I drive with it? On the page there are those data:

- Voltage: 12V-30V
- Current: 5A

So if I understand right I can run the 12V motor that has peak current of 5A? Am I right? Do I need regulated supply for the motor or is it unregulated power supply ok?

### EDIT

[image: L6201P]

I attached specs of LD6201P that is on the PCB.

Comment: The information is here http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13055027228  You just need a good translator :)

Comment: Hmm.. But there is no information how to properly wire this motor driver...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if anyone can provide you the schematics, and if the people who bought you this from should.

However, your board looks relatively simple. It uses an [L6201P](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000089.pdf) chip, which is a "DMOS Full-Bridge Driver". If I read correctly, and if this is an L6201, then the specs are wrong. The datasheet says:

```
- SUPPLY VOLTAGE UP TO 48V
- 5A MAX PEAK CURRENT (2A max. for L6201)
- TOTAL RMS CURRENT UP TO L6201: 1A; L6202: 1.5A; L6203/L6201PS: 4A
```

That answers one of your questions. No, you cannot drive a 12V DC motor that has a peak current of 5A, and again, if I read correctly that this chip is L6201.

Assuming that you will drive a DC motor, you have to have a regulated power supply rated at a maximum of 48V DC or your motor's maximum rating (which one comes first wins). Because, at a given PWM to the chip at different times, the speed will only be the same if the supply voltages are the same at those times. *Let's check this with an example:*

*Example 1:*

```
Supply Voltage: 30V DC
Motor rating: 30V DC
PWM Duty Cycle: 50%
Effective Speed: 50%
```

*Example 2:*

```
Supply Voltage: 20V DC
Motor rating: 30V DC
PWM Duty Cycle: 50%
Effective Speed: 33.33%
```

The difference is because of the supply voltage change. Calculate it yourself, 50% of 20V is 10V. 10V is \$\dfrac{1}{3}\$of 30V. So, the effective speed is 33.33%. I guess that answers one more of your questions.

**Pin-out:**

The green connector on the left is the main power connections. Connect B+ to your supply voltage, GND to the supply GND, M+ and M- to your DC motor in any direction you wish it to turn.

The black male pin headers on the right are control connections. B+ and GND are your supply voltages. EN is the enable input of the chip, which I will come to. RPWM and LPWM are the PWM control inputs for the left side and right side of the bridge, again, which I will come to. Now, at this point, I don't know about CT and VT, but they should be somewhat related to the other IC on the board, LM358.

***EN Pin (Cited from the datasheet):***

```
When a logic high is present on this pin, the DMOS POWER transistors are enabled
to be selectively driven by IN1 and IN2.
```

***RPWM and LPWM Pins (Cited from the datasheet):***

```
Digital Input from the Motor Controller
```

These are PWM inputs from the microcontroller. EN, RPWM and LPWM pins are rated minimum – 0.3 and maximum + 7 VDC. Your 3.3V or 5V microcontroller will work fine. Refer to the datasheet for more info. Here is the block diagram of this chip, IN1 and IN2 are LPWM and RPWM:

[image]

**Edit after OP brought out something that I've missed:**

You are right. L6201P does have an RMS current of 4A. And I was wrong, L6201 and L6201P are not the same. Just to clear things up:

*Specs for L6201 are:*

```
2A maximum peak current
1A total RMS current
```

*Specs for L6201P are:*

```
5A maximum peak current
4A total RMS current
```

Comment: Woww... Your answer is really helpful... Great explanation! Thank you! Just one additional question.. Maybe it is stupid I don't know: Is it possible that CT or VT has something to do with VOLTAGE REFERENCE (on BLOCK DIAGRAM you provided)?

Comment: I don't know, really. Maybe you could try to reverse engineer the board?

Comment: Huh.. It's to much for me... :) I will try to get additional info from the seller...

Comment: I think it is 5A MAX peak current, because it is a L6201P chip, not L6201...

Comment: According to [the search](http://www.st.com/stonline/stappl/productcatalog/app?page=partNumberSearchPage&search=L6201P) on STMicroelectronics site, L6201P is from the L6201 family, so it is not 5A MAX peak current rated.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the answer.. So it's possible to drive 12V, MAX peak 5A current motor... Is there any protection on this board? What happens if for example at the reversing of the motor there will be current more than 5A? Will I damage the chip? Or is there any overcurrent protection?

Comment: @PrimosK if you are driving a DC motor, then the direction only changes the side that the motor turns. There is thermal protection, and the sense resistor let's the board to have some kind of current control, I don't know how actually. You should really trace out how that LM358 is connected, with a multimeter in continuity mode.

Comment: I will try to do that and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do,do not connect the B+ black male header pin to an arduino power supply. If you have power,say 12V connected on the green power side,then this also puts the black B+ to 12 V with disastrous results for the arduino,and your PC if plugged in to USB.

Just check first,put the power on the green side,and test the other black B+ and you will see it go to 12 volts. You have been warned.

The other descriptions above are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I believe CT and VT are for monitoring the load current and voltage.  This is useful for monitoring acceleration (motors take time to spin-up / down), load changes (going up a hill), etc.  A rotation sensor or position encoder also helps for tight speed control.

Excellent resource:
http://modularcircuits.tantosonline.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/